# Themes for Android and iOS development

Tags: android, ios

I'm a web developer but I'm moving in the app development direction. I was just wondering if there is a possibility to buy and download ready made themes that you can use in the development and tweak to your desires? Both for Android and iOS. Thinking about sites similar to themeforest and so on. I did search themeforest but couldn't find more than a couple of themes for app development.

Comment: I think this question might be off-topic at SO.

Comment: ... do you know about http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No i did not know about that. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/material-design-ui-android-template-app/9858746)

But it's better you learn to create your own themes from scratch since you may run into errors in the long run and will need to know how to go about it

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for:)

Comment: @Dennis Always welcome but please consider what I said about learning how to design your own themes

Comment: Yes, i'm in the process of doing that now:) Just find it easier to learn more about how things work when i can see the source of similar templates that i want to build.